# Keycloak - Restrict access to token endpoint

Tags: token, keycloak, endpoint, restrict

I run a keycloak server with a client and have a flutter mobile application that authenticates on user level with keycloak. I do this via Direct access grant.
My question is: is there a way to restrict access to retrieving an access token if the user doesn't have a specific role?

Kind regards

Comment: Yes, you could use some SPI: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/server_development/topics/auth-spi.html